# PHP array_diff_key() is empty but should not

Tags: php, array-difference

I query a series of tables in order to print these, and I want to print all keys of each table even if the values are empty, but a specific set of keys which are the same for each table shall not be printed.

My query and fetch of the result in an array for one table:

```
$stmt = $db_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table;");
$stmt->execute();
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

`var_export($array);`returns:

`array ( 0 => array ( 'a' => '1', 'b' => '2018-12-21', 'c' => '', 'd' => '', ), )`

I prepared a list of bad keys in an array:

`var_export($bad_keys);`returns:

`array ( 0 => array ( 'a' => '1', 'b' => '2019-01-05', ), )`

For each table I want to exclude the bad keys {a, b} from the query result in `$array` by use of `array_diff_key()`:

```
$array_new = array_diff_key($array, $bad_keys);
```

`var_dump($array_new);` returns empty:

`array(0) { }`.

`$array_new` should have the keys {'c', 'd'} but it has not. I don't see a mistake in my code. Please help.

Comment: You should `var_export` arrays to get more people reproducing your code. If there is no easy copy'n'paste code, I do not even read much of the question.

Comment: Sorry I bothered you. I am a beginner. I put my bad keys into a table in the database and queried. `var_export($bad_keys)` returns: `array ( 0 => array ( 'a' => '1', 'b' => '2019-01-05 22:07:18.360', ), )`. The array now contains keys and values. Compared with the second array by array_diff_key returns a new array with non-empty result, but the keys are not filtered out.

Comment: You need a `foreach` to process each rows stored in your result table array.

Comment: My script queries each table in a loop by `for()`, and in the loop tries to filter the bad keys by `array_diff_key()`. Without success.

Comment: I delete your comment in the summary. It does not help but even contradicts my complement.

Comment: There is no `for` in your snippets. Each edit contradicts the former. You fetch a complete table using `PDOStatement::fetchAll`. Btw. `fetchAll` only makes sense in very few cases, can lead to heavy resource loads and is considered as bad practice. There is no obvious reason to call `PDOStatement::closeCursor` in the given snippets since there do not remain unfetched rows.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake: In array_diff_key() I compared two multidimensional arrays without writing the index [0] for each array to be compared.

Solution: I added the index [0] to each array to be compared, and additionally I created an array from the result of array_diff_key()

```
$array = array( 0 => 
     array( 
        'a' => '', 
        'b' => '', 
        'c' => '', 
        'd' => '', 
    ), 
);

$bad_keys = array( 0 => 
     array( 
        'a' => '', 
        'b' => '', 
    ), 
);

$array_new = array( array_diff_key( $array[0], $bad_keys[0] ));

var_export( $array_new );
```

now returns the desired result:

```
array( 0 => 
     array( 
        'c' => '', 
        'd' => '', 
    ), 
);
```

Answer (score 4):

`array_diff_key` is used to compute the difference between the **keys** of two or more arrays, i.e. a new array with all key/value pairs of the *first array argument* having keys not existing in any other **array argument's keys** are returned.

In your code, you try to compare the **keys** of your first array with an array of **values** (i.e. your `$bad_keys`, actually having numbered indexes), not the **keys** of the `$bad_keys` array. This is **not** how `array_diff_key` works.

Be sure to check out the reference at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php

One method giving you only the keys you are looking for as an array:
Just create a new array of the keys of the first array as **values** and then use `array_diff` to compare it with your `$bad_keys`.

To get the key/value pairs you can use this one (as Quasimodo's Clone suggested):

```
array_diff_key($array, array_flip($bad_keys))
```

UPDATE: The keys in the first array are also not at the same level as the keys in the `$bad_array`.

Comment: I reassured myself in the manual before posting. That's what I intended: comparing only the keys of two arrays. The string representation is the same in both arrays, so I do not understand why I can't compare an array that has values with an array that has not.

Comment: Hey Mich, the `$bad_keys` array does not contain any keys–it only has values–hence it can only return an empty array.

Comment: Your answer explains why the code does not work. Not the "difference between the keys" but the key/value pairs *of the first array argument* having keys not existing in any other array argument are returned. A more directive solution is `array_diff_key($array, array_flip($bad_keys));` This already good answer could be improved by that.

Comment: I put my bad keys into a table in the database and queried. In result I see the difference to my earlier array of values, and understand your comment. This is my new array of bad keys: array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["a"]=> string(1) "1" ["b"]=> string(23) "2019-01-05 22:07:18.360" } }. When comparing with my second array by array_diff_key I still get an empty array. Can you give any more hint, Kevin?

Comment: @Quasimodo I tried `array_diff_key($array, array_flip($bad_keys));`. `var_dump();` the array returned a result, but `array_diff_key()` does not filter the bad keys from the second array.

Comment: Oh, took me a while. Just realized your fetchAll returned everything wrapped inside an array. How did you init your new bad_keys? I think the key comparisons might need to occur at the same level. Essentially your fetchAll returned something like this: `array( array( "a"=>blabla, "b" => blabla,... ) )`, but your bad_array has something like this: `array("a"=>blabla, "b"=blabla)`

Comment: @Dr.KevinWang Thus I recommended: **add a copy'n'pastable** `var_export` to your question. It's no fun to read and code from an unformatted dump.

Comment: @Kevin I do not understand "How did you init your new bad keys". I complemented my summary above and added a `var_export()` of the bad keys.

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to see how you defined the bad keys. Just do another var_export on your $bad_keys and you will see what I meant by "key comparisons might need to occur at the same level"

Comment: @Dr.KevinWang Sorry this was accidentially addressed to you by automatic completion, I wanted Mich to add an export to his question. He already has done now (I've formatted it more readable). :)